# Domain name tab missing from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, domain-name

I have installed Android Studio and am in the process of creating a new project. I need to set the Domain name to a specific title but the tab to enter it is missing. There is only "Name",  "Package Name", and "Save Location".

I tried uninstalling then reinstalling it but still have the same result. Based on what I've found on the web it should be there upon instillation.

Does anyone have any experience that might help me with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Google removed the domain name field from the new-project wizard a couple of Android Studio releases ago. Just fill in your package name (a.k.a., application ID), which often is based on a reverse domain name (e.g., `com.commonsware.this.bowl.is.super`).